# Determine the convergence of a sequence and find the limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

A sequence $\{a_n\}$ satisfying

$\displaystyle a_{n+1} =\sqrt{\frac{λ + μ\,a_n}{μ + a_n}}$ , $a_1= c>0$

where $μ> \sqrt{λ}$, $c^2 < λ$. Consider if $\{a_n\}$ converges and if yes, find the limit of it.

Comment: use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) and please include your attempt.

Comment: Ι tried to prove that an is monotonous and bounded so the limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $a_n\geq0$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. If $c\in (0,1]$, then $\lambda>c^2\geq c^3$ and $\mu c\geq\mu c^2$, so
$$\lambda+\mu c>c^3+\mu c^2$$
which equals to $a_2>a_1$. It is obvious that
$$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda+\mu x}{\mu +x}}=\sqrt{\mu-\frac{\mu^2-\lambda}{\mu +x}}$$
is increasing when $x\geq0$ and has a upper bound $\sqrt{\mu}$. Hence we have
$$a_2=f(a_1)<f(a_2)=a_3$$
and then by Mathematical induction, we can get $a_{n}<a_{n+1}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

So we prove that $\{a_n\}$ is monotonous and bounded when $c\in (0,1]$.

But sorry, I haven't done yet the remaining situations.

Comment: Nice!! Now I have to generalize for c>1. If it was c^2 >λ I would have solve it but... :(

Comment: I can't seem to prove that the sequence is monotonous for c>1.Help would be appreciated guys :(